# How to check what div span is placed in

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to find out what div is the span is in using jquery.

here is a eg.

```
 <div id='one'></div>
 <div id='two'></div>
 <div id='three'><span id="find_me"></span></div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.closest()` to find the closest ancestor `div` (`.parent()` will only find it it if the div is the immediate parent).

```
$('#find_me').closest('div').attr('id')
```

Comment: +1 Closest is the most reliable way to do this with the designers constantly changing the HTML structure and positioning of elements.

Comment: Of course if you're going to take it beyond the code example, you should then consider that there could be an intermediate `<div>` with no ID attribute, which would mean you would probably want something like `.closest('div[id]')`.

Comment: @patrick Well, you might want to do something that doesn't involve finding the id, but yes, nice example :-)

Comment: @patrick, technically the OP is asking for the container `div`, not the one with an id ..

Comment: @Gaby - Fair enough, but technically, the code in the question shows no ancestors between the `<span>` and the `<div>` with the ID. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

`alert ( $("#find_me").parent().attr("id") ); // <- three`

Comment: +1 I think this is the only answer that considers the *actual* question being asked. Sure `.parent()` can break with changes to HTML structure, but that's true for `.parents()` and `.closest()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the id of the `<div>` [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) of the `<span>` with the id `find_me`:

```
$("#find_me").parents("div").attr("id")
```

Comment: Not a big deal, but it usually doesn't make sense to specify a tag name with an ID, since there should only be one of any given ID on the page. It just slows down the selector a little bit.

Comment: i think using parent(s) (**with the s**) would be the ideal solution for general use (*since the OP is asking for the div that contains the span*) (*not needed in the specific example though..*) **closest** as @lonesomeday says would be the ideal solution..

Comment: @Gaby Good point. I didn't know about parents. I've changed it.

Comment: @patrick dw - True. Although what happens if you did specify the id more than once? Then what happen?

Comment: Adam - @lonesomeday is right. A selector using `#` to find the element will likely only return the first match.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#find_me').parent()` should do the trick.

Comment: you should use the code button to format your code for better readability. (*i did it for you in this case*)

Comment: Understood. Apologies for any inconvenience.